# Are the conventions for formatting descriptions in nuspec files documented somewhere?

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I've looked around and can't find where the conventions for formatting the description field in a nuspec file are documented. I can see that you can at least add paragraphs but I don't know how it is done and would like to know if there is anything else that can be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's plain text, so paragraphs/tabs etc. are all you get at the moment. It looks like there is a [feature request](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/937) to add support for arbitrary syntax formatting by supporting embedded XML tags describing the parser, or at least standardizing on supporting `markdown`, but no movement on them yet.